# Xamarin.Forms app locks up for no apparent reason

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I really hope someone here can help me out.

With a Xamarin.Forms application for one of our clients I currently have a major issue with the App freezing on iOS. This started as a random issue last year without a pattern behind it, different iOS models and different iOS versions were showing this issue.

The problem for me at the time was that no diagnostics event was triggered in Visual Studio App Center, so I did not have any error messages or crash logs in order to follow up on the issue. Now since upgrading to iOS 16 I have the problem on my phone as well now and strangely enough, we thought it would always trigger on Sundays, but this is not the case, it is random, and the only way to resolve the issue is to uninstall the app and then it will work for a while.

I basically ruled out all the probable causes from our application code, updated all the Nuget packages and even tried an older XCode version. Still, all of my attempts have gathered no results. From what I was able to glean while debugging, the App halts somewhere in Native Code where the Mono Debugger can not follow, so the iOS Device Log is my only hope to figure this out.

***Current behaviour***

1. App launches
2. All data is correctly pulled from Servers
3. Start page is properly updated
4. App remains unresponsive to touch inputs, no errors given

***Visual Studio for Mac Information***

```
Visual Studio Community 2022 for Mac
Version 17.3.6 (build 20)
Installation UUID: 88c2a03b-e426-4318-bd27-fe2b69128c38

Runtime
.NET 6.0.5 (64-bit)
Architecture: Arm64

Xamarin Designer
Version: 17.3.0.208
Hash: 0de472ea0
Branch: remotes/origin/d17-3
Build date: 2022-09-22 15:21:44 UTC

Roslyn (Language Service)
4.3.0-3.22312.2+52adfb8b2dc71ed4278debcf13960f2116868608

NuGet
Version: 6.2.1.2

.NET SDK (Arm64)
SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.401/Sdks
SDK Versions:
    6.0.401
    6.0.400
    6.0.302
MSBuild SDKs: /Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/MonoBundle/MSBuild/Current/bin/Sdks

.NET SDK (x64)
SDK Versions:
    3.1.423
    3.1.422
    3.1.421

.NET Runtime (Arm64)
Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Runtime Versions:
    6.0.9
    6.0.8
    6.0.7

.NET Runtime (x64)
Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet
Runtime Versions:
    3.1.29
    3.1.28
    3.1.27

Xamarin.Profiler
Version: 1.8.0.19
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

Updater
Version: 11

Xamarin.Android
Version: 13.0.0.0 (Visual Studio Community)
Commit: xamarin-android/d17-3/030cd63
Android SDK: /Users/ban/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
    Supported Android versions:
        12.1 (API level 32)
        12.0 (API level 31)
        11.0 (API level 30)
        9.0  (API level 28)
        13.0 (API level 33)

SDK Command-line Tools Version: 7.0
SDK Platform Tools Version: 33.0.3
SDK Build Tools Version: 33.0.0

Build Information: 
Mono: dffa5ab
Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d17-3@7716ae53
SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.38.5@df4deab
Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/main@14076a6

Microsoft Build of OpenJDK
Java SDK: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/microsoft-11.jdk
11.0.12
Android Designer EPL code is available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

Eclipse Temurin JDK
Java SDK: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-8.jdk
1.8.0.302
Android Designer EPL code is available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

Android SDK Manager
Version: 17.3.0.23
Hash: 965bf40
Branch: remotes/origin/d17-3
Build date: 2022-09-22 15:21:49 UTC

Android Device Manager
Version: 0.0.0.1169
Hash: fafb1d5
Branch: fafb1d5
Build date: 2022-09-22 15:21:49 UTC

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 14.0.1 (21336)
Build 14A400

Xamarin.Mac
Version: 8.12.0.2 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: 87f98a75e
Branch: d17-3
Build date: 2022-07-25 20:18:54-0400

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 16.0.0.72 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: 6756a1146
Branch: release/6.0.4xx-xcode14
Build date: 2022-09-21 08:51:06-0400

Build Information
Release ID: 1703060020
Git revision: f7a6334599543f127e737d6de1f362bbe36cebca
Build date: 2022-09-22 15:19:46+00
Build branch: release-17.3
Build lane: release-17.3

Operating System
Mac OS X 12.6.0
Darwin 21.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.6.0
    Mon Aug 22 20:19:52 PDT 2022
    root:xnu-8020.140.49~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000 arm64
```

Below is a iPhone Console Log from the application starting, running and also crashing after tapping around on screen for a few seconds. All messages that are obvious to me I already checked via Google, but no real helpful information came out.

***iOS Device Log***

Due to the length, I published it as a Gist: [iOS Device Log](https://gist.github.com/bnoffer/badebdf947ebe9397d3ae2821f898cfa)

I hope someone can point me in the right direction since we are approaching a major update for the App and we would like to ensure that the App works as intended.

Thank you very much in advance for all the support.

Comment: *"always triggered on Sundays"*: this somehow must be a huge clue as to what code it could be. I would start disabling various major sections of code in app, trying to narrow down where the problem is. Divide and conquer. Keep simulating Sunday. Is it a certain time on Sunday? If you mock the server data (local, hardcoded data from files or compiled-in), so there is no communication with server, does that affect the symptom?

Comment: I actually removed several core modules that would be the obvious causes for issues like that, but the App remained frozen. I would presume when it would be caused by the managed code that if I debug in that state and pause the debugger once the app has fully loaded I would get to some point of the managed code that is the point where the application is hanging, but that is not the case, it points to native code.

Comment: Updated the post due to us observing that it is not only happening on Sundays. That observation has turned out invalid.

Comment: how do you handle the calls to the server? did the call runs on different threads than the UI/main thread? the call is made to an http or https server? did you run the call or the entire method in a try/catch block?

Comment: For the server communication I use Refit and all calls are done on seperate threads using https only, for obvious resons, since http calls on Android are for example prohibited by default.

Comment: And yes, all the calls are wrapped in try/catch blocks that are wired up to trigger App Center Crashes Diagnostics tracking in the catch block.